# Need help on how to interpret Gamma Probability density function of gamma(2, 1/10)

Tags: r, probability, interpretation, probabilistic-programming

The below sample graph was created using R, for an example I came across while reading (on Distribution of time until customer x arrives):

```
t <- seq(0,1,0.01)
ft <- 100*t*exp(-10*t)
plot(t,ft,type="l", xlab="T", ylab="f(t)")
title(main=expression(paste("Probability density function of ", Gamma(2,frac(1,10)))));
```

The graph looks like a Percent Point Function, even though it isn't exactly.Am trying to understand on how I interpret it, but am not getting it.

Can someone help on how to read the above plot?

Thanks,
-Kamal.

Comment: More background information for this question is available [on math.SE](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/903025/15941).

Comment: As the `main` title asserts, this is a probability *density* function.  As you might imagine, this basic tool [appears in thousands of posts here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=probability+density+function), many of which will illuminate the question by showing how such plots are to be understood and read. The basics are explained in the apparent duplicate.